# VBA: Date Export from Excel to SQL Server : SQL Server does not exist or access denied

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I am trying to export data from Excel to SQL Server and I found this code online (I have very limited knowledge of VBA). I am having the following code issue:

> Run time error *-2147467259 (80004005)':
>
> [Microsoft][ODBC SQL SERVER DRIVER][DBMSLPCN] SQL Server does not exist or access denied.

Code:

```vb
Sub testexportsql()
    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim ServerName As String
    Dim DatabaseName As String
    Dim TableName As String
    Dim UserID As String
    Dim Password As String
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim RowCounter As Long
    Dim NoOfFields As Integer
    Dim StartRow As Long
    Dim EndRow As Long
    Dim ColCounter As Integer

    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    ServerName = "xxx\\xxx" ' Enter your server name here
    DatabaseName = "DATAWAREHOUSE" ' Enter your  database name here
    TableName = "dbo.AlbertaFire_import" ' Enter your Table name here
    UserID = "sa" ' Enter your user ID here
    ' (Leave ID and Password blank if using windows Authentification")
    Password = "xxx" ' Enter your password here
    NoOfFields = 331 ' Enter number of fields to update (eg. columns in your worksheet)
    StartRow = 2 ' Enter row in sheet to start reading  records
    EndRow = 200 ' Enter row of last record in sheet

     '  CHANGES
    Dim shtSheetToWork As Worksheet
    Set shtSheetToWork = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
     '********

    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

    cn.Open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=" & ServerName & ";Database=" & DatabaseName & _
            ";Uid=" & UserID & ";Pwd=" & Password & ";"

    rs.Open TableName, cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic

     'EndRow = shtSheetToWork.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For RowCounter = StartRow To EndRow
        rs.AddNew
        For ColCounter = 1 To NoOfFields
        'On Error Resume Next
            rs(ColCounter - 1) = shtSheetToWork.Cells(RowCounter, ColCounter)
        Next ColCounter
        Debug.Print RowCounter
    Next RowCounter
    rs.UpdateBatch

     ' Tidy up
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you change `xxx\\xxx` to your sql server and `DATAWAREHOUSE` to your database in that server and `xxx` to your password for your `sa` user? This is trying to connect with that `cn.Open` line to that SQL Server and it either can't find it (because you gave it a bad network path or IP or because you don't have access with your `sa`/password.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Yes I added the xxx when I posted here. 
The servername and the password are also used from R to SQL (and it works), so I believe the issue comes from somewhere else(?)

Except if the access are different between R/Excel to SQL

Comment: You code looks ok.  Hit F8 over and over.  Which line of code does it error out on?

Comment: @asher Thanks!
it's that lines
  cn.Open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=" & ServerName & ";Database=" & DatabaseName & _
    ";Uid=" & UserID & ";Pwd=" & Password & ";"

Comment: Ok, good to know.  So, one of those variables is incorrect and thus you don't have the correct rights to access that machine.  Make sure you have the correct spelling of the ServerName, UserID, and Password.  Double-check and triple check those variables, and try, try again.